# Google App Engine cron job schedule repeat on days with DST changes

Tags: cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a cron job that should repeat every 3 hours and must land on 9:30 in US/NY time.

If I start the job at 0:30, and run it every 3 hours, will it run at 9:30 on daylight savings days?

The documentation is a bit vague on this: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules#daylight_savings_time.  It uses wall clock time to start, but does it use wall-clock time for each offset as well?

Alternatively, could I start it using 9:30 as the trigger time, and then every 3 hours until 6:30am the next day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, Cloud scheduler uses wall clock time, is expected that the executions changes according the wall time.

To run a job from 9:30am to 6:30am (next day) you need 2 Scheduler jobs

1st will be run every 3 hours starting 9:30 to 23:30

```
30 9/3 * * *
```

2nd will be run every 3 hours  starting 0:30 to 6:30

```
30 0-6/3 * * *
```

I use this [page](https://crontab.guru/#30_9/3_*_*_*) when I have doubts about cron format

Comment: Ok, thats a pretty decent workaround and link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to completely avoid any kind of issue with DST changes is to switch to a timezone unaffected by those, as the documentation states:

> If your job requires a very specific cadence, you may want to consider choosing time zones that do not observe daylight savings time.

A good one would be UTC for example, and as the difference between NY(GMT -4) and UTC(GMT) is 4h you just need to add 4 to your desired starting time.
With that you are assuring that the scheduled hours do not get modified and whatever you are expecting to be run is done as it should.

Regarding the start time of the trigger, it does not matter whether it is 0:30 or 9:30, once you create it, it will run every X hours/mins/seconds as you will have it specified beforehand.